# Let root (/) partition on external drive be loaded by /boot on internal HDD

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, system, grub-efi

I bought an external SSD and I would like to install Ubuntu on it and use it on a PC with UEFI AND a laptop with Legacy BIOS. But that doesn't seem to be possible very easily, it at all.

So I had an alternative idea, since I really want to somehow get it done: Ubuntu is installed on the SSD is in EFI mode and on the HDD of the laptop, a new `/boot` partition is set up, which boots the `/` partition from the external SSD. Is that possible somehow?

If not, which parts of an Ubuntu installation are UEFI / Legacy specific except `/boot`? The rest could then be integrated by logical link into a system that actually runs on the HDD of the laptop, couldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`/boot` is a subdirectory of `/`, so not sure you can do what you think here. My suggestion is to install to the SSD in normal BIOS mode and simply enable legacy BIOS in the PC. Boot the PC and press <kbd>F10</kbd> (or whatever) to select your boot device and choose the SSD whenever you need.

Also, UEFI typically works best with GPT partitions and BIOS with MBR. Trying to make something hybrid might just be more effort than its worth IMHO.

Don't be too afraid to use Legacy BIOS and MBR, it works. This is how I boot from my SSD across multiple machines. I have ISO images bootable from GRUB and a few installs I like to play around with all on one SSD.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'll definitely use Legacy if there is no other option but first I want to see weather it's possible to use UEFI somehow. It is possible to have a extra boot partition seperate from the root partition, that is what I meant. Since I think most boot-mode-specific files are located there, I thought it would be possbile to boot this way.

Comment: It is true you can have seperate boot partition, in fact you can have as many separate partitions as you like and mount any folder you want to them. I dont know how to do specifically what you want. If you dont find a solution then legacy bios will work.

Comment: The big problem with legacy is that what I called an external SSD is actually an existing internal SSD with a Case to make it protable. I'd have to switch the existing Ubuntu and Windows on this disk to legacy. Would probably take plenty effort as well, therefore I'd prefer the way I described.

Comment: What is unique is grub, either grub-pc or grub-efi-amd64. And I used gpt with my old BIOS system starting in 2010, so only use gpt. Actually for external drive should be relatively easy. One of the issues with Ubuntu is with UEFI it only installs the UEFI grub to the ESP - efi system partition on sda or usually internal drive.  And is using gpt you should have ESP  on external even if not currently used. And if BIOS include bios_grub partition on external. Not sure if installing in UEFI mode, then adding grub-pc or vice-versa works better? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace